# Pandas Series and Nan Values for mismatched values

Tags: python, pandas

I have these two dictionaries,

```
dico = {'Name': ['Arthur','Henri','Lisiane','Patrice','Zadig','Sacha'],
        "Age": ["20","18","62","73",'21','20'],
        "Studies": ['Economics','Maths','Psychology','Medical','Cinema','CS']
     
             }
dico2 = {'Surname': ['Arthur1','Henri2','Lisiane3','Patrice4']}

dico = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico)
dico2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dico2)
```

in which I would like to match then append the Surname column with the Name column, to finally append it to dico, for a following output:

```
      Name   Surname Age     Studies
0   Arthur   Arthur1  20   Economics
1    Henri    Henri2  18       Maths
2  Lisiane  Lisiane3  62  Psychology
3  Patrice  Nan       73     Medical
4    Zadig  Nan       21      Cinema
5    Sacha  Nan       20          CS
```

and ultimately delete the rows for which Surname is `Nan`

```
      Name   Surname Age     Studies
0   Arthur   Arthur1  20   Economics
1    Henri    Henri2  18       Maths
2  Lisiane  Lisiane3  62  Psychology
```

```
map_list = []
for name in dico['Name']:
    best_ratio = None
    for idx, surname in enumerate(dico2['Surname']):
        if best_ratio == None:
            best_ratio = fuzz.ratio(name, surname)
            best_idx = 0
        else:
            ratio = fuzz.ratio(name, surname)
            if  ratio > best_ratio:
                best_ratio = ratio
                best_idx = idx
    map_list.append(dico2['Surname'][best_idx]) # obtain surname

dico['Surname'] = pd.Series(map_list) # add column
dico = dico[["Name", "Surname", "Age", "Studies"]] # reorder columns

#if the surname is not a great match, print "Nan"
dico = dico.drop(dico[dico.Surname == "NaN"].index)
```

but when I `print(dico)`, the output is as follows:

```
      Name   Surname Age     Studies
0   Arthur   Arthur1  20   Economics
1    Henri    Henri2  18       Maths
2  Lisiane  Lisiane3  62  Psychology
3  Patrice  Patrice4  73     Medical
4    Zadig  Patrice4  21      Cinema
5    Sacha  Patrice4  20          CS
```

I don't see why after the Patrice row, there's a mismatch, while I want it to be "Nan".

Comment: Will it always be 1 digit at the end of Surname in dico2?

Comment: Because you have a `best_ratio` for *every* case. You might want to use a threshold for it prior to appending to `map_list` i.e. append `"NaN"` when, say, `best_ratio < 0.3`.

Comment: @sophocles, no my actual data is more complex than this, Surname will be more like ```Apple Inc.``` while Name will be ```Apple```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets try `pd.Multiindex.from_product` to create combinations and then assign a score with `zip` and `fuzz.ratio` and some filtering to create our dict, then we can use `series.map` and `df.dropna`:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

comb = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((dico['Name'],dico2['Surname']))
scores = comb.map(lambda x: fuzz.ratio(*x)) #or fuzz.partial_ratio(*x)
d = dict(a for a,b in zip(comb,scores) if b>90) #change threshold
out = dico.assign(SurName=dico['Name'].map(d)).dropna(subset=['SurName'])
```

---

```
print(out)

      Name Age     Studies   SurName
0   Arthur  20   Economics   Arthur1
1    Henri  18       Maths    Henri2
2  Lisiane  62  Psychology  Lisiane3
3  Patrice  73     Medical  Patrice4
```

Comment: Thank you for your help ! However, I get an infinite loop with my actual data, which is way larger, do you have any idea as to why this may be the case ?

Comment: @ArthurLanglois it may be due to extremely large set of combination. How big are the dfs? Also make sure you don't have any duplicate values

Comment: my dfs are respectively 1161392 rows × 3 columns, and 894 rows × 1 columns, for my equivalent of dico and dico2. On another note, there should not be any duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following thing. Define the function:

```
def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, key1, key2, threshold=90, limit=2):
    s = df_2[key2].tolist()
    m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))    
    df_1['Surname'] = m
    m2 = df_1['Surname'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if i[1] >= threshold]))
    df_1['Surname'] = m2
    return df_1
```

and run

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
df = fuzzy_merge(dico, dico2, 'Name', 'Surname',threshold=90, limit=2)
```

This returns:

```
Name Age     Studies   Surname
0   Arthur  20   Economics   Arthur1
1    Henri  18       Maths    Henri2
2  Lisiane  62  Psychology  Lisiane3
3  Patrice  73     Medical  Patrice4
4    Zadig  21      Cinema          
5    Sacha  20          CS
```

Comment: when I run the code on my actual data , I get the following error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`, even though the parameters I put in are strings. Do you have any idea as why this may be the case ?